# Sending HTTP headers by webserver or PHP?

Tags: php, nginx, http, cache, http-headers

It is equally possible to send HTTP headers by webserver or script. I use PHP on Nginx. Is there any different to send HTTP headers (such as Cache-Control) by nginx or PHP?

Is it faster to send headers by webserver? and does it have an effect on earlier processing the HTTP request?

Comment: Either way, it's the web server that *sends* the headers.

Comment: I meant that webserver will send the header defined its in own config before processing the PHP via fastcgi where PHP generates headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any different to send HTTP headers (such as Cache-Control) by nginx or PHP?

Nope, nginx may overwrite (or duplicate headers sent by your application level (PHP using PHP-FPM I guess).

> Is it faster to send headers by webserver?

*faster*? Do you have any performance problems at that level? If not, forget that.

> Does it have an effect on earlier processing the HTTP request?

HTTP headers are sent back to the client, so it happens at the response and not the request time.